# Google Developer Console - how to edit app usage instructions after release is created?

Tags: android, release, google-play-console, developer-console

When creating a new app release on Google Play, you are asked to give instructions on how to use the app if necessary.
I am working on an app that requires login. So I entered the information on how to acquire login credentials, and moved on. Only after I was done I realized that I could simplify this a lot by just providing test credentials for the reviewers.

**Is there any way to edit these instructions again? I can't seem to find them anywhere...**

Using the new Play console design by the way (but can still switch to the old one if necessary)

Comment: This is a serious question, so I really don't understand the immediate downvote. Please let me know why you think this is not a valid question and how to improve it instead of just downvoting and blocking people from seeing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out myself. It looks like the new Play console has a bug here, so I believe this information could be helpful for others.
What you want to do is:

1. Go to Publishing Overview
2. Scroll down to the `App Content` section. App access instructions are not available here.
3. Click on any item in the section
4. Go back
5. You end up on a different screen which shows you a detailed overview of the app content
6. Here you will find that you can select `App access` where the instructions can be changed.